# how to save selected option in select after send form

Tags: javascript, html

I have select in form and i send value from option to my backend

I was wondering if there's way to save value that i've send in my select

template.html

```
<form method="get" class="mb-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8 w-25 custom-select">
            <form method="get" class="w-50 custom-select">
                <select name='ObjectGUID' class="form-select" id="select2">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Выберите объект:</option>
                    {% for obj in objects %}
                        <option value="{{ obj.GUID }}">{{ obj }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                </select>
                <button type="submit" class="mb-3 ms-2 mt-3 btn btn-outline-primary w-50">Применить</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

After i send get request

[image]

But i want select not to switch to default option
[image]

Comment: Use your backend language to set the `selected` attribute in the option, similarly to how you set the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need verify if there's already a value saved for this field, then you can set a selected attribute on your select's option. For exemple:

```
  <select name='ObjectGUID' class="form-select" id="select2">
    <option {% if savedValue == '' %}selected{% endif %}>Выберите объект:</option>
    {% for obj in objects %}
      <option {% if savedValue == obj.GUID %}selected{% endif %} value="{{ obj.GUID }}">{{ obj }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
```

This `savedValue` is the var you have saved on your submit form.